# How can I find the average of radio buttons with different values?

Tags: javascript

On my HTML page I have made a rating system consisting of radio buttons and styled it in CSS so that they look like stars that get filled out. I also made a submit button so that when I press on a star it says: "number of stars: xx"

Here's what I need to do:

In Javascript I need to write a program that will give me the average of the number of stars submitted. So let's say that the user clicks on 3 stars, submits and then clicks on 5 stars and submits again. I want the program to display: "the average star rating is 4". And if the user chooses to submit yet another time it has to calculate a new star rating.

Can anyone help me out?

I found a code to calculate the average but I don't know how to implement it in my program

```
function average (numbers){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
      sum += numbers[i];
  }
  return sum / numbers.length;
}
average([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Most people know how to calculate an average. What no people know is how your page looks like. You should rather show relevant source code portions of your page. The "submit" part is not clear either, do you have a server side too?

Comment: Is your question how to retrieve the radio button that was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, you have some research to do, but you need it, no offense.
In your html something like this...

```
<button onclick="submitRating(someRadioButton.value)" />
```

then in your js...

```
let ratings = []

function submitRating(rating){
    ratings.push(rating);
    console.log("the current average is: " + average(ratings));
}
```

Comment: Yes, let's just say I'm very new at this. 
But if I some how manage to implement the code for calculating the average inside your function, will that help me? 
I'm guessing that ratings.push means taking the new value from the submit button and pushing it to the array?

Comment: This example uses the `average` function you showed above unchanged, so you don't need to implement it, just call it like in my example. Yes, `.push()` puts a value into an array, in this case, the array you use as an argument for `average`. The challenge for you here is to figure out which radio button has been selected and access its value, which you may find you need to do inside the `submitRating` function. Looking at the spec for radio buttons will help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio